# How to add Lets Encrypt to local list of trusted certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.ctr?

Tags: email, ssl, mutt, letsencrypt

### Question

How can I add Lets Encrypt to the file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` ? This file is a list of certificates from trusted CA and I want to add Lets Encryt to it.

I believe that by doing so it will fix a bug that is preventing my mail client from connecting to my mail server.

### Context

I deployed my own iRedmail mail server and now want to set up a mail client. I tried neomutt and thunderbird, but none work. I don't think the error is with the mail clients because they work well for other mail providers, like gmail.

I think the error is with the SSL certificates. See lines below of my msmtp config used by neomutt:

```
tls on
tls_trust_file  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

The SSL certificate of my mail server was issued by Lets Encrypt. Lets Encrypt is not in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Therefore, I think the mail client is rejecting to connect to my mail server because of this.

Comment: LetsEncrypt should not appear under its own name in your truststore; [LE formerly used Identrust's "DST Root CA X3" and recently switched to "ISRG Root X1"](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) -- do you have (either or both of) those? On _most_ Unixy systems the truststore files (plural, not just the one you are looking at) are managed by that system's package manager and should not be manually changed directly, but the correct method to use instead depends on which Linux distro or other Unix type you are using.

Comment: I think I got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181231/server-certificate-verification-failed-cafile-etc-ssl-certs-ca-certificates-c. I was able to get the certificate used by my server. I'll add it to the ca file to see if it works.

Comment: I added my server's certificate to the ca file, but it did not work. So I suppose I was wrong about why I'm unable to use any mail client with my mail server.